# Test website without domain name

Tags: web-development, cpanel, ip-address, testing, whm

I've a VPS with on IP address. WHM/cPanel installed.
I want to test a website, without pointing the DNS to the new server in this test period.
I can change the host file on windows, but I won't be able to test the website on mobile phones in this way (iPhone for e.g. don't allow to change host file).

What can I do?

Comment: If you have public ip address you can test with ip instead of domain. `http://1.2.3.4/index,html`

Answer (score 1):

You can create the test domain as a separate domain in CPanel and then reference it by using your primary domain followed by the test domain name.  I.e., log in to CPanel as though you were going to manage your existing domain.  Next, create your test domain.  Then you can access it via `http://myprimarydomain.com/mytestdomain.com/`

No host file changes are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using suphp as your PHP handler you can use `https://1.2.3.4/~user/directory` if it is in a subdirectory or  `https://1.2.3.4/~user` if it is in your public_html directory.